# Magento 2 Express Shipping Configuration

Tags: magento2, shipping, table-rates

So we currently have setup a number of shipping rules that change the default shipping price for different ranges of products.

However we are now looking to add an express shipping option that is only available for a certain range of products, not all the products in the store. Is there a way to do this? I've been looking into using Table Rates but I don't see how we would limit this to one set of products rather than the whole store.

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Hey, might be a way, I don't know how to do that with the default but you can check some shipping extensions. For example I needed to limit shipping options based on post-code and I couldn't do that without changing the base code so I used https://marketplace.magento.com/owebia-magento2-module-advanced-shipping-setting.html , might help you, you can get the whole cart and make a shipping option appear by sku in cart, check the docs too https://owebia.com/doc/en/magento2-module-advanced-shipping. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Andrew can you speify your plan to, what you are looking for?